# Regex for segment path and negative lookahead

Tags: regex, wordpress

I need to write a regular expression for WordPress redirecting.
I need to add fra/fr only in some cases.

- www.mysite.com -> www.mysite.com/fra/fr
- www.mysite.com/something/somethingelse -> www.mysite.com/fra/fr/something/somethingelse
- www.mysite.com/fra/fr -> www.mysite.com/fra/fr  *(same)*
- www.mysite.com/uk/en -> www.mysite.com/uk/en    *(same)*
- www.mysite.com/uk/en/something -> www.mysite.com/uk/en/something   *(same)*

I can avoid domain and ^ for starting string.

I tried:

```
\/((?!uk\/en|fra\/fr).*)$
```

Substitution rule:

```
/fra/fr/$1
```

but it intercepts 'en' as Group 1, so I get:

```
www.mysite.com/uk/en -> www.mysite.com/uk/fra/fr/en
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use anchor to make sure you are not matching 2nd forward slash in `/uk/en`:

```
^\/((?!uk\/en|fra\/fr).*)$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/gYlFfZ/2)

Comment: I think it's right. But will it work in WP>Tools>Redirect using ^?

Comment: If that plugin is accepting regex then `^` will also be accepted.